# Yammer Followers list

Tags: yammer

Would like to know why Yammer does not show the entire list of followers for a user.
 
In my case, there are 200+ followers, but when I want to see the list of followers, it shows only the top 50 (sorted alphabetically).
Is this a limitation in Yammer itself or can be modified by Admin?

TIA!

Comment: What API method are you calling to get the list of followers? Many of the methods take an offset and/or count parameter so you can continue getting more results. The server has to have some limits to prevent aggressive users from degrading the service for everyone.